# How to return a list into a dataframe based on matching index of other column

Tags: pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have a two data frames, one made up with a column of numpy array list, and other with two columns. I am trying to match the elements in the 1st dataframe (df) to get two columns, o1 and o2 from the df2, by matching based on index. I was wondering i can get some inputs.. please note the string 'A1' in column in 'o1' is repeated twice in df2 and as you may see in my desired output dataframe the duplicates are removed in column o1.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
array_1 = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [3, 4, 6], [1,2,3,6]]) 

#dataframe 1
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': array_1})

#dataframe 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'o1': ['A1', 'B1', 'A1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1'], 'o2': [15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 7, 8]})

#desired output
df_output = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': array_1, 'o1': [['A1', 'C1'], ['C1', 'D1', 'F1'], ['B1','A1','C1','F1']], 
                          'o2': [[15, 18, 19], [19, 20, 8], [17,18,19,8]] }) 
# please note in the output, the 'index 0 of df1 has 0&2 which have same element i.e. 'A1', the output only shows one 'A1' by removing duplicated one.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can explode `df` and use that to extract information from `df2`, then finally join back to `df`

```
s = df['A'].explode()
df_output= df.join(df2.loc[s].groupby(s.index).agg(lambda x: list(set(x))))
```

Output:

```
              A                o1               o2
0     [0, 2, 3]          [C1, A1]     [18, 19, 15]
1     [3, 4, 6]      [F1, D1, C1]      [8, 19, 20]
2  [1, 2, 3, 6]  [F1, B1, C1, A1]  [8, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: I was wondering how would I remove even the duplicate associated with the removed 'A1' , in this case how could i remove the 18 in column o2, index 0? so the number of elements in o1 is same as o2?